# Set Shortcut Key to Launch Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want is to be launched by a keyboard shortcut - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) API.